# How to Get the ID of an HTML element using PHP?

Tags: php, html

Pretty straight forward question and I have no idea how or if it can be done. I've searched the web for a while and haven't found anything. What I'm trying to figure out is if I can get the value of an ID in a html element. For example I want to get `Joe` out of this `<div id="Joe">`. Is there a way to do this? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you have any other attributes to uniquely identify the div?

Comment: @Lal Do you mean like a class or a name? If so, then no.

Comment: On which event you want to get ID?

Comment: Yes..if you have any class names as attribute?

Comment: look into HTML parsers, [`DOMDocument`](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementbyid.php) in particular

Comment: @kailashsharma I want to get the value of the `id` attribute.

Comment: @JoeScotto You are right my friend but when you want the ID. on click of div or on click of Button or on page load?

Comment: are you looking for a JS solution or PHP one?

Comment: @Fadey PHP because I need to convert the ID into a variable. I plan on using the ID as a simple storage spot for a value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be looking for DOM crawlers.. Symphony has a really nice one, and it's pretty straight forward.
you'll find in their documentation all the possible ways of getting attributes out of elements.

You'll need [composer](https://getcomposer.org/) to install the package (it's a lot easier, but not a must)

you can find the package [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dom_crawler.html)

best of luck.

Comment: aside from suggesting this library, you should also demonstrate on how to use this on the OP's case, link answers shouldn't be enough

Answer (score -2):

You can get the value using

```
$('.element').attr('id');
```

but for this you need to add a class something like element on div

Comment: You should also mention that you're using [jQuery](http://www.jquery.com) to do this, and he doesn't want the element, he just wants the `id`'s value.

Comment: he will get this by using any class on it, how he will specify the div although he has included javascript  tag in his question so its obvious.

Comment: *How to Get the ID of an HTML element using **PHP**?*